# Show elements of an array in TkMessageBox

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code i'm using is the following:

```
if len(areUnusedParams) > 0:
   tkMessageBox.showinfo('Error!','The following parameters are unchanged throughout the C-files and are also not present in parameter.txt:\n')
```

Now, i want the contents of `areUnusedParams` (which is an array) to be posted when the MessageBox is displayed and every element should be on their own line.
I was contemplating something like:

```
'\n'.join(areUnusedParams)
```

But I don't know how to implement it, PyCharm keeps complaining when I try to do it.

Comment: have you tried running it despite pycharms complaints? What actually happens when you use `'\n'.join(areUnusedParams)`?  Maybe if they are not already strings then you would need to convert them all to strings with `'\n'.join(map(str,areUnusedParams))`

Comment: Maybe it's how I added it to the messagebox prompt. This is the code i used `tkMessageBox.showinfo('Error!','The following parameters are unchanged throughout the C-files and are also not present in parameter.txt:\n',  '\n'.join(areUnusedParams))` Is it correct?

Comment: Ok, thank you. PyCharm doesn't complain anymore

Comment: yes, I will repost as an answer and delete my comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you add the list of `areUnusedParams` to showinfo as a third argument it will raise a `TypeError` much like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 3, in <module>
    tkMessagebox.showinfo("title","message","thing")
TypeError: showinfo() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Since you intend the `'\n'.join(areUnusedParams)` to be part of the message you need to add it to the message instead of passing as an additional argument:

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo('Error!',
                      'The following parameters are unchanged throughout the C-files and are also not present in parameter.txt:\n' \
                         + '\n'.join(areUnusedParams))
```

I assume that all of `areUnusedParams` are all strings but just to be thorough, if they are not then it is an invalid thing to pass to `str.join` in which case you can cast all of them to strings using `map`:

```
'\n'.join(map(str,areUnusedParams))
```